# retrive quote cart after reorder and delete product

Tags: event-observer, quote, reorder

I am trying to delete a cart after the user has made a reorder.
I'll explain:
I have a module that adds a free product with a shopping cart price rule (whether a product is part of a specific category, add a free product).
The problem comes when the customer makes a Reorder: Magento adds to cart the free product 2 times in addition to products to be reordered.

You know tell me the event to use the type: "retrive the quote cart after a reorder is made"?

I have created a custom module and I used these events in observers:

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after
controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_reorder
```

Thi is my test code:

```
public function checkFreeProducts(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {

            $order_id =Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');

                $promoSKU ='';
                $items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$order_id));
                    foreach($items as $item){
                        //if the item has not had a rule applied to it skip it
                        if($item->getAppliedRuleIds() == '')continue;

                        foreach(explode(",",$item->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleID){        
                            $salesRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($ruleID);
                            $promoSKU = $salesRule->getPromoSku();
                        }

                    }
                if($promoSKU){
                    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
                    $items = $order->getAllItems();
                    foreach($items as $i):
                        $prd_id =  $i->getProductId();
                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prd_id); 
                        $productSku = $product->getSku();

                        if($promoSKU==$productSku){ // there is a promo product 
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('promo product');                      }
                    endforeach;
                }
                $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    echo $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
                    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
                }
```

but I could not see if is applied some cart rules.
Someone can help me?